# Google plus Java API to get Access Token

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

Could any one tell me how would i get access token from googleplus Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications . If you have got any code please paste it here, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following is the way to get the access token but before that you need to get the authorization code

//code for getting authorization code

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(
        CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI,scopes);
         authUrl.setAccessType("offline");
    authUrl.setApprovalPrompt("force");
```

//Code for getting access token

```
 HttpTransport netTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      token = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(netTransport, 
        jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, 
        REDIRECT_URI).execute();
      System.out.println("Valid access token " + token.getAccessToken());
       GoogleCredential cd = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token
        .getAccessToken());
```

This code uses

google-api-client 1.9.0-beta
google-api-services-plus v1-rev11-1.6.0-beta

Comment: token = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(netTransport, 
        jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, 
        REDIRECT_URI).execute();
From where we will get this authorisation code?

Comment: You will get it by using GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl which forms the authorization URL that can be used to request authorization code